# Excel VBA: Searching for value in listbox based on value set in textbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am trying to write a code for a search button which searches a listbox based a specific input set in a textbox.
The values searched are always numbers, and the listbox contains values from a single column.
The code i wrote can be found below but i don't understand why it is not functional.

Legend:

- SearchButton: A Button which upon clicking is supposed to initiate the search
- SearchBox: The textbox which will contain the search value
- AvailableNumberList: The listbox which contains the data

Thanks for your help :)

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
Dim SearchCriteria, i, n As Double
SearchCriteria = Me.SearchBox.Value
n = AvailableNumberList.ListCount
For i = 0 To n - 1
If SearchCriteria = i Then
AvailableNumberList.ListIndex = i
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
'If SearchCriteria = i Then
If AvailableNumberList.List(i) = SearchCriteria Then
```

Also use `Exit For` once a match is found :)

Comment: (I'm kind of a noob in coding so I haven't used the "Exit for" previously) could you please point out where i should set that? Thanks :)

Comment: after the line `AvailableNumberList.ListIndex = i`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @Siddharth Rout solution, this code allows to search in the ListBox even if the TextBox does not have the full word/number:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

Dim SearchCriteria, i, n As Double
SearchCriteria = Me.SearchBox.Value
n = AvailableNumberList.ListCount

For i = 0 To n - 1
If Left(AvailableNumberList.List(i),Len(SearchCriteria))=SearchCriteria Then
AvailableNumberList.ListIndex = i
Exit For
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for their code! =D